# PrimeFaces tags not recognised

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to JSF and Primefaces and have created a project with JSF2.0, Glassfish v3.0 and Jdk 6.0.Now want to use Primefaces tags instead of JSF tags.
I have downloaded primefaces-3.5.jar and added it into WEB-INF/lib folder and it well recognized into my *.xhtml pages.

But when I try to run the application it does not recognizes the PrimeFaces tags.
for Example:
if I insert:

```
<p:inputText id="username" validator="#{regBean.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter Username"/>
```

instead of:

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{regBean.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter Username!"/>
```

it does not show the input box in the Web Application.
Do I need to include any configuration details in web.xml file?
please suggest!!

Comment: Have you included `xhtml:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` inside the page's `<html />` tag?

Comment: Yes, xhtml:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" has been included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
 <p:editor></p:editor>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Also make sure you have primefaces.jar in your path.**

Comment: Hi,The jar is included in my WEB-INF/lib folder and xhtml:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" is also included in all my *.xhtml pages. It gets the <p:> tags in the xhtml files, but when I run the application, it does not show any compilation error, but just tags are not shown at run time!