# p:selectOneMenu Rendering Weird

Tags: primefaces

Following the instructions given on the PrimeFaces [getting-started page](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/getstarted.xhtml), I am seeing an odd rendering from `SelectOneMenu`. It doesn't look the way I'd expect. Does anyone know why?

[image: Rendering]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

   <h:body>

      <h:form>
         <p:selectOneMenu id ="selectOneMenuCategorie" value="#{selectOneController.categorieSelected}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" noSelectionOption="true"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{selectOneController.categorieList}"
                           var = "c" itemLabel="#{c.libelle}" itemValue="#{c}"/>
            <f:ajax render="selected_item1"/>
         </p:selectOneMenu>

         <h:outputText id="selected_item1" value="#{selectOneController.categorieSelected.libelle}"></h:outputText>

      </h:form>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems like your primefaces is not yet installed. As I have run your code in my project and it works. 
Show your console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PrimeFaces tags not recognised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542224/primefaces-tags-not-recognised)

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
 <h:head>
</h:head>
```

tag to your xhtml page.

The `<h:head>` is a JSF component which provides a hook to programmatically include JavaScript and CSS resources in the generated HTML `<head>`. PrimeFaces uses it to include the necessary JS/CSS code for the Ajax works and fancy look'n'feel.

As a test, create a page with a `<h:head>` and a `PrimeFaces` component, open the page in the webbrowser and check the generated HTML source by rightclick - *View Source*. You'll see that several JSF and PrimeFaces specific JS/CSS files are been added. Now replace `<h:head>` by `<head>` and check the generated HTML source once again, you'll see nothing this time.